# Will the NASA Commercial Crew "zip line away from the tower and into" this "military armoured truck" in case of emergency? Does the truck have a name?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, identify-this-object, safety, mission-anomaly

The NASA Commercial Crew [@Commercial_Crewtweet](https://twitter.com/Commercial_Crew/status/1499752039420731394)

> The #Crew4 astronauts have been busy getting ready for their upcoming mission to the
> @Space_Station!
>
> The crew recently participated in simulations focused on undocking and departing the orbiting lab, emergency preparedness training, and more: https://go.nasa.gov/3KhJllY

Also shows the image below.

David Parise [@davidparise2 tweets](https://twitter.com/davidparise2/status/1499753451869417473)

> What is that beast of a vehicle?

and Scottish [@Scottish720 replies](https://twitter.com/Scottish720/status/1499756434224988167)

> Pretty sure it’s a military armoured truck in the case the crew / ground crew are on top of the tower and something goes wrong they zip line away from the tower and into the trucks and zoom away from the pad

**Questions:**

1. Will the NASA Commercial Crew "zip line away from the tower and into" this "military armoured truck" in case of emergency?
2. Does this armoured truck have a name?

Possibly related (maybe there's a bit of a similar vehicle in the photos)

- [Why does this researcher have a "clear plastic bag" over their head?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29986/12102)

---

[image: NASA Commercial Crew tweeted image March 4, 2022 https://twitter.com/Commercial_Crew/status/1499752039420731394]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For #1, it certainly sounds like there's something zip-wire-ish involved:

> ...slide-wire baskets carrying astronauts and ground personnel from the top of the crew access tower

For #2, [it is a "MRAP"](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/mrap-rolls-through-pad-evacuation-runs-0) (mine-resistant ambush-protected) vehicle of a type designed for use as general-purpose armoured transport/patrol vehicles in Iraq/Afghanistan. A group of them seem to have been acquired in about 2015.

[WP clarifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRAP) that the term covers about a dozen types from different manufacturers - there was no single model - and while it mentions NASA, it doesn't say which type. However, it looks like this was a [BAe Caiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAE_Caiman) - that article mentions NASA use, with a picture looking very much like this one, and it seems to have the distinctive bulge on the sides.

During the Shuttle era, they used [ex-Army M113 armoured personnel carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variants_of_the_M113_armored_personnel_carrier#NASA_Armored_Rescue_Vehicle), now phased out.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34625/slide-rope-way-from-launch-pad-of-space-shuttle/34626#34626

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/ground-personnel-proximity-to-space-shuttle-at-launch/27580#27580

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/content/emergency-egress-vehicle-arrives-at-kennedy-space-center Confirmed its a Caiman "The team selected the slidewire system and the army’s MRAP Caiman, a military vehicle that was used for operations in Iraq and Afghanistan."

Comment: There's great video of the [Shuttle-era slidewire baskets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGMWdtQYkbc) being released for the last time before decommissioning in 2012. And also [video of the new slidewire emergency egress system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9a4I1vkNhw) being tested for Crew Dragon.